# read from file into a dictionary which value is a tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

i have this file called chocolates.txt:

Mary;dark;0.5
Steve;dark;0.5
Mary;toffee;2
Mary;white;0.25
Steve;raspberry;1
Mary;milk;1.25

i have to write a code read_data that returns a dictionary like this:
`>>>read_data('chocolates.txt') {'Mary':[('dark', 0.5), ('toffee', 2.0), ('white, 0.25), ('milk', 1.25)], 'Steve': [('dark', 0.5), ('raspberry': 1.0)]}'`

so the dictionary values are lists of tuples.
I tried to do something like this (so that first I put all the data into sets and then turn them into tuples but my code doesn't work.

```
def read_data(file):
d = {}
f = open(file, encoding='utf-8')
for row in file:
    x = row.strip().split(";")
    buyer = x[0]
    if not buyer in d:
        d[buyer] = set()
        kd[buyer].add(x[1:])
    f.close()
    return d`
```

Is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use sets for this.

Open the file and read one line at a time. Strip any leading/traing whitespace. Split on semi-colon (expect 3 tokens).

Use setdefault to append to a list keyed by the "buyer"

```
def read_data(file):
    d = {}
    with open(file) as data:
        for line in map(str.strip, data):
            buyer, v, n = line.split(';')
            d.setdefault(buyer, []).append((v, float(n)))
    return d
```

...should do what you need

Comment: thank you so much!can you also explain how can i change the amount of chocolate in the tuple when a user wants to buy more? sorry if this is a stupid question, tuples still confuse me

Comment: @Maria Tuples are immutable - i.e., you can't change them. However, creating a new tuple based on the contents of another tuple is trivial